# Type annotation of a class inside its own class

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and I'm adding type annotations to a JS file I had, and I'm wondering if doing something like this is right or not. And if not, what's the right way of doing it? As you can see below I added the Bomb type to the static method `(p: Bomb)`

TS in the VSC is not showing any errors.

```
class Bomb {
  type: string;
  color: string | null;
  image: object;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  isActive: boolean;
  usingColumns: number[];
  usingRows: number[];

  constructor() {
    this.type = "bomb"
    this.color = null,
    this.image = bombImage,
    this.x = 120,
    this.y = 0,
    this.isActive = true,
    this.usingColumns = [3],
    this.usingRows = [0]
  }

  static explode(p: Bomb) {  // <---- Can I do this? 
     // Some code to destroy surrounding pieces
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should work fine. The only problem with the code you posted is that `bombImage` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks @Julia .. I don't know why it feels wrong to do that.. But now that I think about it, the explode method accepts parameters from outside the class, so it makes sense to verify if it's actually of the same Class. `bombImage` is an Image object that I initialize outside the class.